# Unable to upload file using django

Tags: python, django

I'm unable to upload a file using django. When I hit submit button I get "This webpage is not available. The webpage at http://127.0.0.1:8000/results might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address." error in chrome.

For the file upload HTTP query the corresponding webserver's log entry is:

```
[02/Jul/2010 17:36:06] "POST /results HTTP/1.1" 403 2313
```

This is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 

<head> 
 <title>Content Based Image Retrieval System</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="site-content/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
 <div><img src="site-content/images/logo.jpg" /> </div>
 <form name="myform" action="results" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data>
  <div align="center">
  <br><br>
  <input type="file" size="25" name="queryImage">
  <br><input type="submit" value="Search"><br>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
```

entry in urls.py:

```
(r'^results$',upload_and_search),
```

view that handles the file upload:

```
def upload_and_search(request):
    if request.method != 'POST' or request.FILES is None:
        output = 'Some thing wrong with file uploading'
    handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['queryImage'])
    output = 'success'
    return HttpResponse(output)

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('queryImage', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

**EDIT:**

I've also tried changing the destination line `destination = open('queryImage', 'wb+')` to `destination = open(os.environ['TMP']+'\\'+filename, 'wb+')`. Its still giving the same error. Also the file I'm trying to upload is less than 2.5MB.

**EDIT 2:**

I've added a print statement in the first line of `upload_and_search`.Its not printing anything. i.e.. its not not even entering the function. I also checked if something is wrong with my url mapping by directly accessing the url http:// 127.0.0.1:8000/results. Its working fine. I think there is some problem with server configuration. I've no clue how to configure this server or what to configure. I'm stuck! I've no clue about what to do.

Comment: What are the permissions for the directory that you're trying to write queryImage in?

Comment: you have also error in ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data <-missing "

Comment: +1 for supplying all the relevant info in your very first question.  Looks like *somebody* read the FAQs.  ;-)

Comment: Can you put in some logging (or even just `print` statements to the console) to see if Django is hitting the `upload_and_search` view at all, and if it's correctly triggering the `handle_uploaded_file` function?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman : please see the editied question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess its because of csrf http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

try changing your from

```
<form name="myform" action="results" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
```

an the view generating it

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def showIndexPage(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("index.html", c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filename = f['filename']
destination = open('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT, filename), 'wb')
```